# How to prevent Firestore write race conditions for a reservation button

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

### Summary

I'm developing an application where users can reserve and cancel reservations for classes. In a `ReservationButtonView` I two buttons that add and remove a user to a workout class respectively. Currently the button I show is based off whether the user's Firebase Auth uid is listed in a Firestore document.

I was having issues when rapidly tapping on the reservation button. Specifically, the `reservationCnt` would become inaccurate by showing more or less than the actual users reserved for a class.

The only way I have found to resolve this is be using a Firestore transaction that checks to see if a user is in a workout class already. If they are, `addReservation()` now does nothing. If they aren't, `removeReservation()` would also do nothing.

At first I thought I could just disable the button and via the logic still in place the code below (`.disabled()`), but that alone didn't work as I ran into the above described race conditions. What I found out is that `arrayUnion` and `arrayRemove` still succeed even when the object I'm looking to add is there and not there respectively. Meaning it is possible for my transaction to not remove a `reservedUser` that isn't there and also decrease the `reservationCnt` which can leave me with say no reserved users and a `reservationCnt` of -1

### The Ask

Is there a better way to handle this reservation process? Can I accomplish this without a transaction for at least the removal of users in some way. Ideally, I'd like to have a spinner replace the button as I add or remove a user's reservation to indicate to the user that the app is processing the request. Perhaps I need two variables to manage the `disabled()` state instead of one?

### MVVM Code Snippets

NOTE: I pulled out some button styling to make the code a bit less verbose

**ReservationButtonView**

```swift
struct ReservationButtonView: View {
    var workoutClass: WorkoutClass
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: WorkoutClassViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    var body: some View {
        if checkIsReserved(uid: authViewModel.user?.uid ?? "", reservedUsers: workoutClass.reservedUsers ?? []) {
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.isDisabled = true
                viewModel.removeReservation(
                    documentId: workoutClass.id!,
                    reservedUserDetails: ["uid": authViewModel.user?.uid as Any, "photoURL": authViewModel.user?.photoURL?.absoluteString ?? "" as Any, "displayName": authViewModel.user?.displayName ?? "Bruin Fitness Member" as Any],
                    uid: authViewModel.user?.uid ?? "")
            }){
                Label(
                    title: { Text("Cancel Reservation")
                        .font(.title) },
                    icon: { Image(systemName: "person.badge.minus")
                        .font(.title) }
                )
            }.disabled(viewModel.isDisabled)
        } else{
            Button(action: {
                viewModel.isDisabled = true
                viewModel.addReservation(
                    documentId: workoutClass.id!,
                    reservedUserDetails: ["uid": authViewModel.user?.uid as Any, "photoURL": authViewModel.user?.photoURL?.absoluteString ?? "" as Any, "displayName": authViewModel.user?.displayName ?? "Bruin Fitness Member" as Any],
                    uid: authViewModel.user?.uid ?? "")
            }){
                Label(
                    title: { Text("Reserve")
                        .font(.title) },
                    icon: { Image(systemName: "person.badge.plus")
                        .font(.title) }
                )
            }
            .disabled(viewModel.isDisabled)
        }
    }
}

func checkIsReserved(uid: String, reservedUsers: [reservedUser]) -> Bool {
  return reservedUsers.contains { $0.uid == uid }
}
```

**WorkoutClassModel**

```swift
struct reservedUser: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var uid: String
    var photoURL: URL?
    var displayName: String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case uid
        case photoURL
        case displayName
    }
}


struct WorkoutClass: Codable,Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var reservationCnt: Int
    var time: String
    var workoutType: String
    var reservedUsers: [reservedUser]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case reservationCnt
        case time
        case workoutType
        case reservedUsers
    }
}
```

**WorkoutClassViewModel**

```
class WorkoutClassViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isDisabled = false
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()

    func addReservation(documentId: String, reservedUserDetails: [String: Any], uid: String){
        let incrementValue: Int64 = 1
        let increment = FieldValue.increment(incrementValue)
        let addUser = FieldValue.arrayUnion([reservedUserDetails])
        let classReference = db.document("schedules/Redwood City/dates/\(self.stateDate.dbDateFormat)/classes/\(documentId)")
        db.runTransaction { transaction, errorPointer in
            
            let classDocument: DocumentSnapshot
                do {
                    print("Getting classDocument for docId: \(documentId) in addReservedUser()")
                    try classDocument = transaction.getDocument(classReference)
                } catch let fetchError as NSError {
                    errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
                    return nil
                }

            guard let workoutClass = try? classDocument.data(as: WorkoutClass.self) else {
                    let error = NSError(
                        domain: "AppErrorDomain",
                        code: -3,
                        userInfo: [
                            NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to retrieve workoutClass from snapshot \(classDocument)"
                        ]
                    )
                    errorPointer?.pointee = error
                  return nil
                }
            
            let isReserved = self.checkIsReserved(uid: uid, reservedUsers: workoutClass.reservedUsers ?? [])
            
            if isReserved {
                print("user is already in class so therefore can't be added again")
                return nil
            } else {
                transaction.updateData(["reservationCnt": increment, "reservedUsers": addUser], forDocument: classReference)
                return nil
            }
            
        } completion: { object, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                self.isDisabled = false
            } else {
                print("Successfully ran transaction with object: \(object ?? "")")
                self.isDisabled = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeReservation(documentId: String, reservedUserDetails: [String: Any], uid: String){
        let decrementValue: Int64 = -1
        let decrement = FieldValue.increment(decrementValue)
        let removeUser = FieldValue.arrayRemove([reservedUserDetails])
        let classReference = db.document("schedules/Redwood City/dates/\(self.stateDate.dbDateFormat)/classes/\(documentId)")
        db.runTransaction { transaction, errorPointer in
            
            let classDocument: DocumentSnapshot
                do {
                    print("Getting classDocument for docId: \(documentId) in addReservedUser()")
                    try classDocument = transaction.getDocument(classReference)
                } catch let fetchError as NSError {
                    errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
                    return nil
                }

            guard let workoutClass = try? classDocument.data(as: WorkoutClass.self) else {
                    let error = NSError(
                        domain: "AppErrorDomain",
                        code: -3,
                        userInfo: [
                            NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to retrieve reservedUsers from snapshot \(classDocument)"
                        ]
                    )
                    errorPointer?.pointee = error
                  return nil
                }
            
            let isReserved = self.checkIsReserved(uid: uid, reservedUsers: workoutClass.reservedUsers ?? [] )
            
            if isReserved {
                transaction.updateData(["reservationCnt": decrement, "reservedUsers": removeUser], forDocument: classReference)
                return nil
            } else {
                print("user not in class so therefore can't be removed")
                return nil
            }
            
        } completion: { object, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                self.isDisabled = false
            } else {
                print("Successfully ran removeReservation transaction with object: \(object ?? "")")
                self.isDisabled = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkIsReserved(uid: String, reservedUsers: [reservedUser]) -> Bool {
      return reservedUsers.contains { $0.uid == uid }
    }
}
```

### App screenshot

Reservation button is the green/grey button at the bottom of the view

[image: app screenshot]

Comment: This is a lifecyle issue. Your object still exists somewhere when you're adding/removing a reservation. You need to update that value earlier in the lifecycle. So either track that down or set your reservation button to only work once. Personally I'd go with the latter option. A simple bool that's set to true the moment you tap the button.

Comment: I don't think only letting the button work once will work for me as I want users to be able to reserve, cancel a reservation, and reserve again. I could see this stemming from a lifecycle issue, so I'll look into that further and see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: Turns out toggling `isDisabled` directly after the Firestore transaction is a bad idea. My conditional in my view is dependent on a Firestore listener which is updating a little after the transaction is complete, thus causing a race condition.

This makes sense for why the check I put in the transaction stops the behavior, but ideally I need to find a way to attach the `isDisabled` boolean to the Firestore listener instead.

Comment: Is issue resolved?

Comment: Not completely. I now know the root cause of the issue I'm facing, but need to better understand how to avoid it / accommodate it. I suspect state in the UI shouldn't be based off a Firestore listener value. I'll look to edit the question down after I've had a second to check SO if UI state managed by Firestore listeners has been asked before.

Comment: The state of the button should be controlled by the listener and nothing else. When the user taps the button, the button should change its state instantly because you should be getting back a latency-compensated return from the listener (synchronously). Only when the write is actually written to the database will the listener return again with another snapshot, but this won't change the state of the button because it was changed by the synchronous return.

Comment: If you monkey test this button and press it a bunch of times, all you're doing is performing a bunch of writes on the document and eventually the listener will resolve the state of the button with the last-executed write. The button can never be out of state if the listener has full control over it. As to the counter, I would consider removing the incrementer/decrementer pattern and simply displaying a calculation for the count, especially considering that a class size is never going to be an astronomical number.

Comment: I would also make this entire task idempotent so that no matter when the user taps the button, regardless of the actual state of the server, if the button was tapped when it was labeled "cancel" then it will cancel the reservation whether or not the user is even in the class and, because you've removed the incrementer/decrementer pattern, it could never throw the class size out of sync.

Comment: I don't quite understand how I can change the state instantly if the state is controlled by the listener. Right now I display the button based on `workoutClass` which is a document I'm listening for changes on. When I click "reserve" the button stays as "reserve" until the transaction completes and the listener is updated. How would I change the state instantly? I do like the idea of removing the counter and displaying a calculation, this actually seems like it would reduce complexity (I then wouldn't need a transaction to remove a user from a class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by adding a disable check conditional before the conditional that decides whether to show the "Reserve" or "Cancel" button.

This way when my Firestore transaction is running the user will see a spinner instead and can't monkey test the button. The spinner helps to show that the reservation operation is in progress. When the transaction hits its completion block I disable the `isDisabled` Bool and the listener is in sync (the user then sees the newly toggled button state)

```swift
if workoutClassVM.isDisabled {
            ProgressView()
                .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: Color("bruinGreenColor")))
} else if checkIsReserved(uid: authVM.user?.uid ?? "", reservedUsers: workoutClass.reservedUsers ?? []) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is a race condition, You have already acknowledged the use of Transactions for the update which is the most desirable as this can ensure the update is successful before allowing the App to change button status.
I.e. by using a transaction and only updating the UI Button state on success, which is explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOVSr0OsAoU&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=11)

The recommendation is to keep the state of the button mapped to what is in the document, therefore you are likely to exceed rate [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#read_and_write_operations) by updating the same field continuously based on the flipping of the button.
Another way to handle this tracking of the state of enrollment is to add a new document that indicates the state of the enrollment for the user to a collection that is the class they are enrolling in.
I.e. Rather than having the class user enrolling into being a document, make that a collection and each time the enrollment state changes, write a new document. This will allow for updates to occur without using transactions and the current state of enrollments is contained within the latest document. This latest document can be read and used as the status of the button within the App with the added benefit that the state will always update to the status contained within Firestore.

Comment: @Thomas Burke Posted an answer, Is it helpful?